# Implementation of multiple-point statistics in GIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, spatial-statistics, c++

Is there any implementation of multiple-point statistical algorithms in GIS? at least for spatial interpolation. [code for instance](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352711016300164).

Comment: Although I am not sure if they have implented this, it might be worth taking a look at [PySal](https://pysal.org/)

Comment: Nice, I am reading it right now. It is a powerful geostat package, but still MPS is not implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPSlib has a Python Interface. Here is a link to the [docs](https://mpslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python-interface.html) that includes installation instructions and examples.

Applying it to spatial data would depend on your exact use case, but [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) and [fiona](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona) are two libraries that will help getting raster and vector data into python.

Comment: I accept your answer. I just wanna ask one more thing, do you think is a good idea yo use MPS for spatial interpolation? for example this kind of data: https://mrdata.usgs.gov/magnetic/show-survey.php?id=WA_4272_pg.shp

Comment: @PaulGoyes, That's a tough question: is model X good for data Y? For that data I really have no idea. I'd recommend defining what "good" means for you in this situation, run MPS, and see if the results hit your meaning of good. Not a particularly helpful answer, though.